# AuditQuerySystemPolicy() function throws AccessViolationException for "Security State Change"

Tags: c#, security, audit-logging

I'm working on a program that will compile information about the audit policy of a local system. Here is my code:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AuditQuerySystemPolicy(
        Guid pSubCategoryGuids,
        uint PolicyCount,
        out IntPtr ppAuditPolicy
    );

    ...

    void getSubCategories(AuditPolicyCategory category, long guidSize) {
        IntPtr ppAuditSubCategoriesArray = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint pCountReturned = 0;
        Guid catGuid = category.CategoryGuid;
        bool result = AuditEnumerateSubCategories(ref catGuid, false, out ppAuditSubCategoriesArray, out pCountReturned);
        if (!result) {
            throw new Exception($"[AuditPolicyCategory::getSubCategories] {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}");
        }
        long ptr = (long)ppAuditSubCategoriesArray;
        for (int i = 0; i < pCountReturned; i++) {
            var guid = (Guid)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)ptr, typeof(Guid));
            string name = getSubCategoryName(guid);
            Console.WriteLine($"Current subcategory: {name}");
            AuditType state = getPolicyStatus(guid);
            //do something with the result
            ptr += guidSize;
        }
        AuditFree(ppAuditSubCategoriesArray);
    }
```

The exception is thrown when the below method hits the `AuditQuerySystemPolicy()` function. It throws an `AccessViolationException` regardless of the value of `catGuid`:

```
    AuditType getPolicyStatus(Guid guid) {
        IntPtr ppAuditPolicy = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool result = AuditQuerySystemPolicy(guid, 1, out ppAuditPolicy);
        if (!result) {
            throw new Exception($"[AuditPolicyCategory::getPolicyStatus] {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}");
        }
        if (IntPtr.Zero.Equals(ppAuditPolicy)) {
            throw new Exception($"[AuditPolicyCategory::getPolicyStatus] invalid audit policy returned");
        }
    
        //do something with the result
    }
```

I've tried running the program in an administrative context, and I've also granted my account the *Manage audit and security log* User Right Assignment. Not sure where to go with this next.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the target platform from `Any CPU` to `x64` to escape the .NET sandbox